# SQLite populate table

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Hey i have this piece of code:

```
-(void)populateTexts{
    self.texts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    FMDatabase *db = [[FMDBDataAccess alloc] init];

    self.texts = [db getTexts];
}
```

i keep getting the error:
TextMsgViewController.m:41:17: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'FMDatabase *__strong' with an expression of type 'FMDBDataAccess *'

TextMsgViewController.m:43:19: No visible @interface for 'FMDatabase' declares the selector 'getTexts'

Comment: What is this `FMDBDataAccess` class? Shouldn't that line be `FMDBDataAccess *dbaccess = [[FMDBDataAccess alloc] init];`?

Comment: Why do you allocate an array and then throw it away two lines later??

Comment: (Basically, you don't know what you're doing.  Please attempt to understand classes and pointers before delving into database stuff.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

> TextMsgViewController.m:41:17: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'FMDatabase *__strong' with an expression of type 'FMDBDataAccess *'

means what it says. `[[FMDBDataAccess alloc] init]` creates an object of type `FMDBDataAccess`. But your variable `db` is declared as `FMDatabase *db` so it expects to point towards an object of type `FMDatabase`. `FMDatabase` and `FMDBDataAccess` are different types.

The next error:

> No visible @interface for 'FMDatabase' declares the selector 'getTexts'

is similarly straightforward. The compiler looks at the interface of `FMDatabase` because that's the type of `db`. That class doesn't have a method called `getTexts`. So the compiler can't figure out the return type and can't verify your code.

Do you mean `db` to be of type `FMDBDataAccess`?